# Trim off last directory/folder without using GetParent()

Tags: c#, iphone, filesystems

I am trying to emulate what "cd .." does, but without using Getparent().

input: /var/mobile/Documents/

actual output: /var/mobile/Documents/

desired output: /var/mobile/

```
    public ArrayList JumpUpDirectory()
    {
        ArrayList directoryListing = new ArrayList();
        StringBuilder storedPath = new StringBuilder();            

        foreach (var directories in storedPreviousDirectory.Split('/'))
        {
            storedPath.Append(directories + "/");                
        }

        storedPath.Replace("//", "/");
        directoryListing = iPhoneFileSystemBrowse(storedPreviousDirectory);

        return directoryListing;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, and what's the problem you're having?

Comment: Code above does not produce /var/mobile/, which is what I want it to do.

Comment: And *why* don't you want to use GetParent? If you're going to rule out the method deliberately *designed* to get the parent directory, you should tell us why.

Comment: Please explain the problem in detail.  What *does* it produce, if it doesn't produce the desired output?

Comment: I'm using a differnet file system that doesn't have GetParent available. It produces the same thing as what is inputted to it.

Comment: Also, when GetParent hits a directory it can't access, it dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string input = "/var/mobile/Documents/";
var parts = input.Split(new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
parts.RemoveAt(parts.Count - 1);
string output = string.Concat("/", string.Join("/", parts), "/");
```

Comment: If you don't remove the empty entries then you don't need to add them back in when you're done.

Comment: Pretty close, but I need to return an arrayList. The other function it delivers to is expecting that, then does a bunch of things with an arrayList.

Comment: @Servy True, but I like my data to be clean :)

Comment: @user2216791 You need to return directoryListing = iPhoneFileSystemBrowse(output)